# When loading a package, R is unable to load libRlapack.dylib

Tags: r, package

I recently updated my R (on Mac) from Version 3.0.2 to 3.1.1. I tried to load a package by using `library(WRScpp)`

But I got an error as shown below:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/WRScpp/libs/WRScpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/WRScpp/libs/WRScpp.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/WRScpp/libs/WRScpp.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘WRScpp’
```

It seems that R tried to load `libRlapack.dylib` by looking for it in the wrong directory (it looked for it in the Version 3.0 directory). I wonder what can be done to direct R to search the correct directory?

Comment: did you try re-installing the package?

Comment: Yes, I did. It installed just fine. I suspect that it has to do with the way the shared object `WRScpp.so" was compiled. I have the raw C++ script, so I can compile it myself. But I just don't know what the problem is.

Comment: can you build it from source and also install it from source